# Нужно проверить расстановку запятых в примерах

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Ты должен сдать этот экзамен на "четверку", хотя бы на "тройку".

Тебе хотя бы на "тройку" сдать этот экзамен. (Где здесь поставить запятые? Кавычки нужны?)

Answer (score 2):

Всё правильно: запятая нужна, кавычки не нужны.

Комментарий

Здесь, скорее, не уступительный оборот (это же не обособление), а однородные члены, связанные уступительным союзом ХОТЯ БЫ. В этом случае однородные отношения называют дифференцированными, а в качестве диф. элементов применяются наречия, частицы, модальные и вводные слова, например:

Он купается в озере осенью и даже зимой. Нужно было его подождать или хотя бы позвонить. Этот маяк высокий и поэтому более заметный.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна безусловно, здесь же уступительный оборот.

А вот кавычки тут совершенно излишни. Тройка и четверка, во-первых общеизвестная вещь, а во-вторых, значение прямое - ведь эти школьные оценки соответствуют реальным цифрам 3 и 4, которые и называют тройкой и четверкой.